# Get the output of fabric.local or run or sudo when the command fails with error

Tags: linux, error-handling, output, warnings, fabric

I'm using fabric to run linux commands for the purpose of networking api
I would like to get the output of the commands when they **FAIL** with an error!
When I do

```
from fabric.api import local, env

result = local("command", capture = True)
```

If the command succeed I get the output
but If there was an error I get an exception.

when I add a fallback like this:

```
result = local("command || echo 'Failed'", capture = True)
```

I get 'Failed'
I would like to get the exact Error as given by shell command.

If I do:

```
env.warning_only = True
result = local("command")
```

I can let the program continue to work and I see the "Error" descriptions as warnings on the terminal when I send a request that will fail
but I want to get these  "Error" descriptions on my program to return them to client.

with this code:

```
env.warning_only = True
result = local("command")
```

I can only get result.return_code which can be 0 (success) or 1 or 2
when I add capture=True to the last code I don't get return_code and I get the
output only if command succeed

Example: I have bridge "br-vxlan55" and a vxlan vxlan55, I added the vxlan to the bridge, after that if the user wants to add the same vxlan to the same bridge, the Error should be returned in the request response as it was shown on the terminal:

```
local("sudo brctl addif br-vxlan55 vxlan55")
local("sudo brctl addif br-vxlan55 vxlan55")#AGAIN
```

Terminal output:

---

device vxlan55 is already a member of a bridge; can't enslave it to bridge br-vxlan55.

Warning: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'sudo brctl addif br-vxlan55 vxlan55'

---

And I get 1 as retun_code
I want to get "**device vxlan55 is already a member of a bridge; can't enslave it to bridge br-vxlan55.**" on my program as an output of local. Is that possible ?

This is only an example, I have so many other commands which may fail, and I want to get the errors descriptions to return them as request response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, it is with "stderr" I didn't know about it

```
from fabric.api import local, env
env.warn_only = True # if you want to ignore exceptions and handle them yurself

command = "your command"
x = local(command, capture=True)
if(x.stderr != ""):
    error = "On %s: %s" %(command, x.stderr)
    print x.return_code # which may be 1 or 2
    print error
    raise Exception(error) #optional
else:
    print "the output of %s is: %s" %(command, x)
    print x.return_code # which is 0
```

Comment: I would add that changing `env.warn_only` like that is quite brutal. Using contextmanager leads to better settings management. Just wrap the block with `with settings(warn_only=True):` and don't forget to add `from fabric.api import settings`.